# Why does Rxjs unsubscribe on error?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

In short:
How to proceed listening after an error in stream without putting a `.catch` before every `.subscribe`?

If you need more details they are here:

Lets assume I have a Subject of current user or null. I get the data from API sometimes and send to the Subject. It updates the view accordingly.
  But at some point error occurs on my server and I want my application to continue working as before but notify some places about the error and KEEP listening to my Subject.

Initially I thought that if I just do `userSubject.error(...)` it will only trigger `.catch` callback and `error` handlers on subscribes and skip all success handlers and chains.
  And if after I call `userSubject.next(...)` all my chains and subscribers will work as before

BUT unluckily it is not the case. After the first uncaught `.error` it unsubscribes subscribers from the stream and they do not operate any more.

So my question: Why???
And what to do instead if I want to handle `null` value normally but also handle errors only in some places?

Here is the link to RxJs source code where Subscriber unsubscribes on error
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts#L140

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Rx` observables [follow the grammar](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#executing-observables) `next*(error|complete)?`, meaning that they can produce nothing after `error` or `complete` notification has been delivered.

An explanation of why this matters can be found from [Rx design guidelines](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc/designguidelines#31-the-rxjs-grammar):

> The single message indicating that an observable sequence has finished ensures that consumers of the observable sequence can deterministically establish that it is safe to perform cleanup operations.
>
> A single failure further ensures that abort semantics can be maintained for operators that work on multiple observable sequences.

In short, if you want your observers to keep listening to the subject after a server error has occurred, do not deliver that error to the subject, but rather handle it in some other way (e.g. use `catch`, `retry` or deliver the error to a dedicated subject).

Comment: If you have some reason to pass on the error yet still not close the observable, then you can just catch and return the Error instead of throwing it. That way the type of the observable goes from Observable<T> to Observable<T | Error> and the observable doesn't close on error.

Answer (score 5):

Every Observable emits zero or more `next` notifications and one `error` or `complete` but never both.

For this reason, Subjects have internal state.

Then it depends how you construct your chain. For example you can use `retry()` to resubscribe to its source Observable on error.

Or when you pass values to your Subject you can send only `next` notifications and ignore the other two:

```
.subscribe(v => subject.next(v));
```

Or if you want to throw error when the user is `null` you can use any operator that captures exceptions and sends them as error notifications. For example like this:

```
.map(v => {
    if (v === null) {
        throw new Error("It's broken");
    }
    return v;
})
```

Anyway it's hard to give more precise advice without any code.