# Why does subscriber hear old error on a Subject?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a subject

```
const subj$$ = new Rx.Subject();
```

and late subscriber

```
subj$$.next('value');

setTimeout(() => {
  subj$$.subscribe(console.log, console.error);
}, 500);
```

as expected nothing happens after 500ms

BUT...

if I throw error

```
subj$$.error('error');

setTimeout(() => {
  subj$$.subscribe(console.log, console.error);
}, 500);
```

late observer handles this error!!!

Why?
I think it is logical to have consistent behaviour for late observers.
And do not notify them but it is not the case

Comment: The `Subject` class doesn't re-play any values. That's what `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` do.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand answer as the same as here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45478765/2772394

So error is also complete but with error so 
all late observers are notified that Sequence has already been finished (regardless of error)