# Unsubscribe not working on subscription interval in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am subscribing to an interval and on error the interval should be unsubscribed. Also on ngDestroy it should undescribe. However when I go to another component on my website I can still see where it is polling the server.

**Using rxjs 6.2.1**

Here is my code

```
private polling: Subscription;

ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.polling){    
    this.polling.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

 loadContacts(){
    this.polling = interval(10000)
                .subscribe((val) => {
                  this.resourceService.getQueryUserPresence(this.contacts[0].Email).subscribe((response) => {
                    console.log('polling for ' + fullName);                    
                  }, (error: any)=> {
                    console.log('Error Getting Status:  ' + error)
                    if(this.polling){
                      this.polling.unsubscribe();
                      }
                  });
                }, (error: any)=> {
                  console.log('Error polling:  ' + error)
                  if(this.polling){
                    this.polling.unsubscribe();
                    }
                })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476902/why-does-rxjs-unsubscribe-on-error), there is **no need** to unsubscribe after the observable **throws an error** or **completes**.

What I think is wrong in your code is that you subscribe to that request in the **first subscribe handler**, which is why you won't be able to see the error in the **second callback**.

It is like having something like this:

```js
interval(1000)
 .subscribe(
  () => {}, 
  () => { console.log('I will never be able to catch an error just from an observable that emits values at certain interval!') }
)
```

One way to solve this is by placing you **API call** within a [pipeable operator](https://medium.com/@sachilaranawaka/rxjs-pipeable-operators-773dbbc8b4c1) like `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, `exhaustMap`, `concatMap`, depending on your use case.
(The aforementioned operators are also called [high-order operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)).

```js
this.polling = interval(1000)
 .pipe(
  mergeMap(() => this.resourceService.getQueryUserPresence(this.contacts[0].Email))
 )
 .subscribe(
  response => console.log('polling operation successful!', response),
  err => console.log('error caught from the API call!', err)
 )
```

### EDIT

> start polling but only go into the webAPI call if the this.contacts.length is > 0

I think you can use the [`skipWhile`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/skipwhile.html) operator.

```js
this.polling = interval(1000)
 .pipe(
  skipWhile(() => this.contacts.length === 0),
  mergeMap(() => this.resourceService.getQueryUserPresence(this.contacts[0].Email))
 )
 .subscribe(
  response => console.log('polling operation successful!', response),
  err => console.log('error caught from the API call!', err)
 )
```